# mtrr_add() function causing "WARNING: "mtrr_add" [/path/to/module.ko] undefined"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, gcc-warning

I have a kernel module where I'm trying to use `mtrr_add()` function. When I compile my code, I'm getting `WARNING: "mtrr_add" [/path/to/module.ko] undefined!`. I found a mail list message: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/510277/ which mentions the removal of `mtrr_add()` and replace with `arch_phys_wc_add()`. If I understood it correctly, `arch_phys_wc_add()` is for adding `Write Combine (WC)` type. Is there any replacement function for `mtrr_add()` that will add `writeback(WB)` type? Or any workaround?

My init module code is following,

```
#include <asm/mtrr.h>
//#include <uapi/asm/mtrr.h>

static int __init car_init(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "car module loaded\n");

   int mtrr_add_r =  mtrr_add(0xf7c20000, 4096, MTRR_TYPE_WRBACK,0); <-- throwing undefined warning
   //int mtrr_add_r = arch_phys_wc_add(0xf7c20000, 4096);
   printk( KERN_ALERT "mtrr_add_r: 0x%x\n",mtrr_add_r);
   set_cpus_allowed_ptr(current,&saved_cpu_mask);

   return 0; 
}
```

`dmesg` shows:

> module_name: Unknown symbol mtrr_add (err 0)

My kernel version : `Linux xxx 4.4.0-200-generic #232-Ubuntu SMP`

gcc version : `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: I don’t understand why you need this. Modern x86 CPUs support PAT, hence one may simply call `memremap()` or `ioremap()` with corresponding flags.

Comment: @0andriy, did not know that. thanks